# ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [psdghi:baseTblColName]

Tags: oracle, trigger

I am trying to create a 'before' trigger for each row on a view. The trigger will be based on an event that occurs on a specific column, which is an invisible column (hidden_column = YES).
I have tested the trigger when the column is visible, and there are no issues; the trigger functions properly. Could you please confirm if triggers do not work on invisible columns?

Comment: `ORA-00600` errors indicate a possible bug in the software. They can only be diagnosed by Oracle Support.

Comment: What pmdba said, and likely that error could be fixed by a recent patch, or newer version of Oracle.